I am getting the following error: Node.js v21.6.2 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting
I am getting the following error when trying to run my application. I am learning backend development. please help me.
I am using nodemon to run my application. I tried several codes to fix the problem following the instructions in stackoverflow but could not solve the issue.

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read about how to aks. Also make sure to add a minimal, reproducible example. In your case adding the error message that was logged besides [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting would also be helpful.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
